# Parse data from XML files(that contains "self-closing tag") and output to csv file

Tags: c#, xml, csv, powershell

I have a big xml file, which is in format as below, and I want to transform it in csv otput as shown below. 
How can I do this, for example with, powershell, C#,....?

```
  <name type="p" id="1" country="Uk">
      <prof>
        <option1/>
        <option2/>
        <option3/>
      </prof>
  </name>
   <name type="p" id="2">
      <prof>
        <option1/>
        <option2/>
      </prof>
  </name>
   <name type="p" id="3"  country="USA">
      <prof>
        <option2/>
        <option3/>
      </prof>
  </name>
```

And the csv output I need is:
     "id","country","prof"
      1,Uk,'option1,option2,option3'
      2,'option1,option2'
      3,USA,'option2,option3'

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. To answer the question as stated may take a significant amount of effort. You need to show some effort into solving the problem yourself before you can expect much assistance from us. Please explain what methods you have tried and describe how well they worked. As it stands your question is likely to be voted down and closed as being too vague and not providing enough information about what you have tried. See also the help link (at the top of this page) about what sort of question can be asked here on Stack overflow.

Comment: I know some general info like: $Data = [Xml] (Get-Content C:\Data\list1.xml
$Data.nvd.entry | Export-Csv -Path C:\Data\list2.csv –NoTypeInformation
 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XSLT 2.0 (e.g. using Saxon or XmlPrime, which can both be invoked from C#) it's

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="@country"/> 
    <xsl:text>,'</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="prof/*/name()" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>'&#xa;'</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Plus some trivial code to add the header line.

Comment: That's great thank you so much!

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/names/name">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="@country"/> 
    <xsl:text>,'</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="prof/*/name()" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>'&#xa;'</xsl:text>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score -2):

In C# you can use below approach to handle the xml file

```
public void GenerateCsv(string filePath)
{

  if (File.Exists("Details.xml")) {
        //Loading xml document with information
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("Details.xml");       

        XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//nameList"); //specify root element of your xml document      

        foreach(XmlNode node in dataNodes) {
           if(node.attributes != null)
           {
               string id= node.Attributes["id"].Value;// reading attribute values 
               if(node.HasChildNodes)
               {
                 //loop through child nodes to get the data
               }
           }

        }
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("No data to read");
    }


}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question...

Comment: @DGibbs can you explain why it is not answering question as xml file needs to read n then write in csv format correct me if im wrong

Comment: He needs the output in CSV format. This does not do that. Your XPath is wrong too.

Comment: @DGibbs he wanted it done using C# if im not mistaken csv is text file which he can create using the code i have provided extracting data in xml is the important aspect in my view and Im showing an example of doing it not an concrete solution thank you for your response

Comment: I agree that i have not describe all the steps to create csv but i have shown hw to get data so in my view my answer provides a solution

Comment: Your answer doesn't even solve the parsing of the XML data since your XPath selector is wrong. It doesn't show how to get the child options, it doesn't show how to get the country or type. Secondly, it doesn't show how to use this data to create a csv in the format the OP has specified, it simply does not answer the question. That you think it does demonstrates how you've failed to grasp the fundamentals of what he's asking for.

Comment: with due respect @DGibbs stackoverflow is not place to provide complete solutions as of my understanding if we can guide someone or help someone that is more important people who raise questions needs to do their homework

Comment: Correct, it is out of scope for answers on SO to provide complete solutions, however they should absolutely answer the question being asked (providing said question is within scope in the first place) - which yours does not.

Comment: @DGibbs Il improve my answers next time but rejecting my answer is outscope is not fair anyway thank you for your valuable feedback.If possible please provide better solution which i can consider a reference solution for similar problem.Thank you